# Script html websites with c++?

Tags: c++, html, web

I was wondering if there's a way for scripting websites with c++ instead of or in addition to javascript? DO I put

```
<script type = "text/c++" src="script.cpp">//code here</script>
```

?

Comment: what exactly are you trying todo? You can't just combine two languages like that.

Comment: Like how you can program html with javascript by doing <script type = "text/javascript">  can you do the same with c++?

Comment: No. You can't do this. For one thing, C++ is not a scripting language.

Answer (score 3):

The only language supported reliably (in script elements) across browsers is JavaScript.

Internet Explorer also supports VBScript. Given a plugin from ActiveState (which I think may be discontinued now) IE also supports PerlScript.

You can embed a program written in C++ using ActiveX — but that requires Internet Explorer on Windows on x86 hardware (so not Windows 8 RT) and is blocked by default security settings.

You can use any language you like for server side code, providing you can interface it with a webserver. CGI and FastCGI provide standard interfaces with supporting libraries for most languages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to use a web framework like TreeFrog. TreeFrog is a full-stack web development framework, so you would be able to use C++ for both the front and back ends.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work as soon as you write your own browser that contains a C++ compiler (or parser). Please tell me which browser that is, so that I can make sure it never gets anywhere near any of my machines, since I definitely wouldn't want a full-fledged C++ program running on my machine - what's to say it's not got code in it that can do harm to my machine (delete files, write to registry, whatever)?

If you actually want your web-clients to have a private program of yours, you'd better distribute it in an already compiled executable or browser plugin [but beware that like me, many others probably won't download it unless you are part of a reputable organisation].

Comment: peterson So there's no way to have, lets say, an input box on a websitethat would function as the cin command in c++?

Comment: That's not quite what I said, you can't ship C++ code inside your web-page. I would suggest that you are asking an XY question, you have an idea that you'd like to do X, and to do so, you want to use Y mechanism, so you ask how to do Y. Now, in this case, it's almost certain that Y is the WRONG way. In general, it's better to ask a mechanic how to fix a puncture than how to loosen a wheelnut, since loosening a wheelnut is only PART of what you need to do.